# Пустой клик js как пофиксить?

Tags: javascript, события

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.className == "cell") {
            this.openCell(e.target)
        }
    }.bind(this))
    this.arr = [];
    this.flag ;
}

openCell(domElement) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
        if (domElement == this.field[i].cellElement()&& domElement !== this.flag) {
            this.arr.push(this.field[i]);
            this.flag = domElement;


            for (let k = 0; k < this.arr.length; k++) {
                this.arr[k].removeId();
                if (this.arr.length > 2) {
                    if (this.arr[0].cellElement().getAttribute("data") == this.arr[1].cellElement().getAttribute("data")) {
                        this.arr[0].empti();
                        this.arr[1].empti();
                        this.flag = ''
                    } else {
                        this.arr[0].addId()
                        this.arr[1].addId()
                        this.flag = ''
                    }
                    this.arr.length = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

первый клик - пушу элемент в массив(там открываю его), второй клик - пушу второй элемент в массив (открываю его), третий клик - очищает массив, но не добавляет в него новый элемент.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это состояние после 2х кликов, на третий - закрываются картинки, но не открывается новая. За счет чего лишний клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что вы хотели - вы очищаете массив `this.arr.length = 0;`
Делайте на третий клик сперва очистку, а **ПОТОМ** добавление элемента

Comment: согласен с вами, есть представление как это реализовать ?

Comment: this.arr.push(this.field[i]);  эту строку выполнять после очистки массива